# Splitting rows information into equal interval in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a following table-
borehole_id depthfrom   depthto depth   color

```
DWASA030    0   3   3   Brown
DWASA030    3   6   3   Yellow
DWASA030    6   15  9   Grey
DWASA030    15  18  3   Black
DWASA030    18  21  3   Brown
DWASA030    21  30  9   Light Brown
DWASA030    30  34  4   Light Brown
DWASA030    34  37  3   Light Brown
DWASA030    37  46  9   Light Brown
DWASA030    46  82  36  Light Brown
DWASA030    82  104 22  Light Brown
```

What I need to do is to split the row into equal interval of 2 meter (in the negative direction, i.e., -2 meter interval). The output table will create an additional column (‘divide’), which, account  the interval in the negative direction. If there is data which end up in an odd number, it will consider the previous information. For example, the first row has information, where the brown color of soil exists until 3-meter depth from the top. So, it will start from 0, and then continue with the -2-meter interval. And then for the next level upto 4, it will continue with the existing value which is brown color. 
borehole_id depthfrom   depthto depth   Color   divide

```
DWASA030    0   3   3   Brown   0
DWASA030    0   3   3   Brown   -2
DWASA030    3   6   3   Yellow  -4
DWASA030    3   6   3   Yellow  -6
DWASA030    6   15  9   Grey    -8
DWASA030    6   15  9   Grey    -10
DWASA030    6   15  9   Grey    -12
DWASA030    6   15  9   Grey    -14
DWASA030    6   15  9   Grey    -16
DWASA030    15  18  3   Black   -18
DWASA030    18  21  3   Brown   -20
DWASA030    18  21  3   Brown   -22
```

A feedback or how to do this in MATLAB would be very helpful.

Comment: Generally, it is recommended to post some sample code, as well as what you have searched on so far. Based on my understanding however, I have posted an answer below. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

## You would use [discretize()](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/discretize.html).

As I understand, the borehole table lists, *in order of occurring depth*, the location of each borehole. To find which borehole is encountered at a particular depth, one can treat the borehole start depths as "dividers" or "bins".

I have not yet tested this code, but you would do something along these lines:

```
% The depth at which each borehole starts.
startDepths = boreTable(:, 2)

% The range of depths to check for which borehole occurs.
checkDepths = 0:2:max(startDepths)

% Row indices that tell which borehole occurs
ind = discretize(checkDepths, startDepths)

% Generate the table with the new list of indices
boreTableNew = boreTable(ind, :)
```